# Is there a "Take 20" mechanic?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

Most d20 systems have a "take 20" mechanic as per [the d20 SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/usingSkills.htm)

> When you have plenty of time (generally 2 minutes for a skill that can normally be checked in 1 round, one full-round action, or one standard action), you are faced with no threats or distractions, and the skill being attempted carries no penalties for failure, you can take 20. In other words, eventually you will get a 20 on 1d20 if you roll enough times. Instead of rolling 1d20 for the skill check, just calculate your result as if you had rolled a 20.
>
> Taking 20 means you are trying until you get it right, and it assumes that you fail many times before succeeding. Taking 20 takes twenty times as long as making a single check would take.
>
> Since taking 20 assumes that the character will fail many times before succeeding, if you did attempt to take 20 on a skill that carries penalties for failure, your character would automatically incur those penalties before he or she could complete the task. Common “take 20” skills include Escape Artist, Open Lock, and Search.

I haven't found anything in the [M&M 3e SRD](https://www.d20herosrd.com/#TOC-ROUTINE-CHECKS), but the 2e rules had it, and maybe I was looking on the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, as far as I'm aware, one system in M&M 3e for guaranteeing a 20 on a d20 dice roll: the Ultimate Effort advantage.

> **ULTIMATE EFFORT (FORTUNE)**
>
> You can spend a Victory point on a
>   particular check and treat the roll as a 20 (meaning you don’t need to
>   roll the die at all, just apply a result of 20 to your modifier). This
>   is not a natural 20, but is treated as a roll of 20 in all other
>   respects. You choose the particular check the advantage applies to
>   when you acquire it and the GM must approve it. You can take Ultimate
>   Effort multiple times, each time, it applies to a different check.
>   This advantage may not be used after you’ve rolled the die to
>   determine if you succeed.

I will grant that there is a difference between this and what you're asking, but it has the advantage of being able to be used to get a 20 in six seconds. Based on this, it seems reasonable for a player to increase the time required to complete the check by a factor of 20 (approximately +5 time ranks) so they can be guaranteed a roll of 20, assuming the following conditions apply:

1. Plenty of time (normal time rank +5, approximately)
2. No distractions (not in a fight)
3. No penalty for failure
4. No possibility of an unknown failure

Even analyzing Inventing, Artificing, and Rituals reveals that this is inefficient for the most broken potential uses for it as compared to routine checks, so I wouldn't worry too much about this mechanic upsetting the balance of your game if used for Perception checks or Knowledge checks. As opposed to missing a vital clue, it might even keep your campaign on-track.

Comment: Quickness is where it kind of falls apart, since it only costs about 5 ranks to be able to "Take 20" in the same amount of time [(excepting that they kind of broke Quickness in 3E via a bad copy-paste)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/176292/does-quickness-work-in-the-midst-of-battle-without-skill-mastery?rq=1), but I agree with the meat of your answer.